# Automatically create new user and silently use for Windows service installation using Visual Studio Installer

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2008, windows-installer

I have a Windows service that is installed using the Visual Studio (2008) installer.  I wanted to avoid running as System, so I have been manually 1) creating a new Windows account on the computer and 2) entering in the computername\username   and password during installation.

I would like to have this require little user intervention, so I am interested in creating a new Windows user and automatically supplying the computer name, username, and password.

How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

[Taken from this website](http://windowsitpro.com/article/articleid/15064/how-can-i-add-a-user-from-the-command-line.html)

> The simple answer is to use the net
>   user    /add
>   (/domain) , however it is possible to
>   automate not only the addition of the
>   user, but also his/her addition to
>   groups and the creation of a template
>   user account directory structure. Many
>   organizations have a basic structure
>   with word, excel directories and some
>   template files. This can be automated
>   with a basic script. For example

```
REM addnew.bat

net user %1 password /add /homedir:\\<server>\users\%1 /scriptpath:login.bat /domain
net localgroup "<local group>" %1 /add

REM repeat for local groups
net group "<groups>" %1 /add /domain

REM repeat for global groups
xcopy \\<server>\users\template \\<server>\users\%1 /e
nltest /sync /server:BDCname

REM repeat for all BDCs you might be authenticating to
sleep 20
cacls \\<server>\users\%1 /e /r Everyone

REM remove the everyone permission to the directory
cacls \\<server>\users\%1 /g %1:F /e
cacls \\<server>\users\%1 /g Administrators:F /e
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom action within your MSI to run the "sc.exe" command (which is installed on WinXP and newer systems). If you are concerned that sc.exe might not be on the system, then include it in your MSI, in either the binary table, or installed with the product.

After your MSI creates the service, have the custom action run the following (modify for your own user/pass):

> sc config **the_service_name** obj=
>   **thedomain\johndoe** password= **stackoverflow**

However, please note that storing the password directly in the MSI in clear text is an EXTREMELY bad idea.

An easy (and basic) solution is to use the [free tool CPAU](http://www.joeware.net/freetools/tools/cpau/index.htm) to encrypt the entire sc command above. You would encrypt this command (using CPAU) from your own system, and then pass this encoded string to CPAU (which you would need to include within your MSI, or install on the system --- in your custom action). CPAU will decode the string you pass in, which will decode to the sc command above, and will more securely set username and password on the service.

Comment: Mick,
If I'm reading you correctly- you're still not describing a way to create a new user -- simply how to (more securely) assign a username and password to start the service, right?

Comment: also  The processInstaller in visual studio *does* allow you to set a username and password for the installation - would that be the equivalent (security-wise) of having the sc utility configure the service (in cleartext) or does VS handle that better?

Comment: True, I'll add a new comment with a way to do this.

Answer (score -2):

I think this will jeopardize user's security and if the service application is permitted to do this, it's also a bad practice. It'll also break the current security credentials.

As far as I know, any kind of windows service is running a task that is supposed to be background task and it's always running in the background. And it's always created with this intent: running background task and it's always running, therefore any kinds of dangerous actions that require user permission (i.e., user has to be aware of) such as creating new user.

If I'm not mistaken, then by all means, your service application will always create new users without any notification since Windows service is always running in the background and doesn't have any UI. Therefore in the application maintainability side, it's also not recommended. Not to mention debugging Windows service is quite hard for many of us.

Comment: I'm not asking for my service to continually create user accounts - I'm asking about how to create a user account *for* my service upon installation.  Part of my objective is to have better security, because I can created a user with more limited privileges than the superuser.

Comment: Oh, you haven't said that on your initial question. It's quite easy then, just create custom actions on your MSI installation and you're done. You can find many samples of these on MSDN.

Comment: How will this *break* current security credentials? That statement doesn't make much sense. He's essentially creating a service account. This is not unusual, and can be secured. It doesn't mean it can interact with the desktop, just that is running with a different set of rights/credentials.